# Apache2 outputs static assets as binary

Tags: azure, apache, kubernetes

I am running a the official PHP-apache image in a `Kubernetes` cluster. All works fine and gets deployed as expected. When i run the image locally also all is working as expected.

However when running this inside the cluster something weird happens with some of the assets. When i try to download a file or image, these are returned as some sort of binary when it happens via http. When i check the files itself all is fine.

```
shopware@app-685bf796f5-bxn47:/app/public/media$ curl localhost:8080/media/test.txt
s: bytes
Content-Length: 4
Content-Type: text/plain

foo
��|��w��AsR����)�rs�uc_���NY��[4��)������[^_8��U�0Gϲ��z�5��5�������B٬X�l�;�I��)�@S��{R���)� �B�
��"d����IQ����J�=�jQ�^z���+���,����*qa�����4�


shopware@app-685bf796f5-bxn47:/app/public/media$ cat test.txt 
foo
```

After some further investigation the issue seems to be related to the PersistentStorageClaim to with an `azurefile`. When i change this back to an `emptyDir` all seems to work fine again.

I tried also to add a custom `storageclass` for this but without success:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: azurefile-retain
provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-file
mountOptions:
  - dir_mode=0777
  - file_mode=0777
  - uid=1000
  - gid=1000
  - mfsymlinks
  - cache=strict
  - nouser_xattr
reclaimPolicy: Retain
allowVolumeExpansion: true
parameters:
  skuName: Standard_LRS
```

Comment: Please share yamls for deployment also, so [minimal reproducible example will be presented](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).